# ASCII to ISO Latin-1 conversion in C++

Tags: c++, ascii

I have a ASCII string of 5 bytes, and i need to convert it to ISO Latin-1 form. I am using c++. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASCII is a subset of iso-8859-1 so the conversion is essentially a no-op.

Comment: Ya, you are right, and also same i read over documents that ISO 8859-1 is a extended version of ASCII. So that means assigning to ISO 8859-1 at least 128 character of ASCII table are not going to have issues. Am i correct ?

Comment: @Aseem: ASCII (the standard) only has 128 characters (0x00-0x7F). And ISO 8859-1 is a strict superset, adding only characters between 0x80 and 0xFF